# AWS CD with CodeDeploy for Docker Images

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-ecr

I have a scenario and looking for feedback and best approaches.  We create and build our Docker Images using Azure Devops (VSTS) and push those images to our AWS repository.  Now I can deploy those images just fine manually but would like to automate the process in a continual deployment model.  Is there an approach to use codepipeline with a build step to just create and zip the imagesdefinitions.json file before it goes to the deploy step?

Or is there an better alternative that I am overlooking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a build step (eg. CodeBuild) to automate generating your imagedefinitions.json file, [there's an example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html).

You might also want to look at the recently announced CodeDeploy ECS deployment option. It works a little differently to the ECS deployment action but allows blue/green deployments via CodeDeploy. There's more information [in the announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/the-aws-developer-tools-improve-continuous-delivery-support-for-aws-fargate-and-amazon-ecs/) and [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/build-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-for-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-as-source/).